# Multi-Select values not staying checked on screen flow

Tags: visual-workflow, multi-select, screen-flow

I have a screen flow component on the Account object that lets users make selections and save their changes. The component is always visible so that users can see the current selections for that Account. One of the fields on the screen flow is a multi-select picklist. When I make and save selections on the multi-select, the selections are being committed to the database (based on values populating in Reporting), but the screen component reflects blank values for the actual multi-select field. Trying to figure out how to display the multi-select value selections in the screen flow component after the changes have been saved.

Comment: Do you mean your choices are not selected any more after navigating to the next screen and back? But are your other choices still there? Or what do you mean? Maybe some screenshot of the flow and/or the respective form would help a tired man comprehend...

Comment: Correct, the choices for the multi-select are no longer there once I hit save, but the other selections for the other fields are still there, which is the intended behavior.